# Ubuntu. startx не работает. Чёрный экран

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, xfce

Уже месяц пытаюсь разобраться с одной проблемой. У меня ноут бук с 3 ГБ оперативки. На нём стоит Ubuntu server 16 и я не могу стартовать иксы. То есть ничего что должно рисоваться не появляется. Сначало думала что проблема в ноут буке. Но на Debian 9 та же проблема. После чего пыталась установить xfce4, однако тоже не сработало. Последний эксперимент провалился. Я пыталась установить xfce4 с сайта на котором помимо этого предлагалось установить login (т. е. графический). Так вот когда появился login, отрисовалась только его рамка и значок ubuntu на нём. Должен был появиться текст приветсвия, но его нет. Зато появилась мышка которой можно было управлять, однако она не фокусируется на поле ввода. Помогите пожалуйста. Я не задаю вопросов на stackoverflow, стараюсь всё делать без него, много чужих вопросов осмотрено, но причина мною не найдена. Я хочу узнать может ли проблема быть в драйверах, т. е. марка ноут бука - Fujitsu Siemens, до этого на нём стояла Винда 7, и она исправно работала.

UPD: Выхлоп `lspci`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115901/discussion-on-question-by-anna-d-ubuntu-startx----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выжимка из каментов:

На безгуёвую ubuntu очень удобно ставить xfce **не** через собственно установку xfce, а через установку метапакета `xubuntu-desktop`, который сам поставит нужные пакеты и пропишет всякие `startx` в нужные места:

```
sudo aptitude -y install xubuntu-desktop
```

Т.к. железо старое (GeForce 8200M G, что видно из lspci) и графика не стартует, то [надо поставить](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213912) оригинальные дрова от nVidia:

```
sudo aptitude -y install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings
```

Comment: сначала надо удалить nouveau, а это немного сложнее `sudo aptitude`

Comment: @PavelGridin, неужели `sudo aptitude -y purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` сложнее? Да и зачем, если на моём хосте вот прям щас установлен `xserver-xorg-video-vmware` и он мне никак не мешает?

Comment: через `tasksel` удобно устанавливать гуйню

Comment: Согласен, достаточно удобная фигня с пачкой интересных пресетов.